# Power BI - formatting matrix table individual cells

Tags: powerbi

Team,
I'm trying to format individual cells within a Power BI matrix table.  It wouldn't be a conditional formatting because it's not based on the values of the cell, rather it's based on the intersection of my X and Y labels.

The first image is my starting matrix table and the second image is how i'd like to format the cells.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the Table Heatmap visual. it is for free. Tick the 3 dots and click "Get more visuals".

[image]

Comment: Yes, I reviewed that Power BI widget prior to posting.  The Table Heatmap works based on the values within the cell.  I'm trying to 'hard code' my color formatting to a specific X / Y intersection ... not the value contains in the cell.

Comment: Then I would still use this widget, as it seems it is more a static approach, you do also know the row and column index for that cell. So I would add this extra column and calculate based on row/column, the color.